# Array Aggregation / Collection - Need to specify struct fields explicitly?

Tags: google-bigquery

So in BQ standardSQL, using ARRAY_AGG, do you always need to specify the struct fields?  Or can this be dynamic as the result  (e.g *)

e.g a memberRoleId can have multiple memberships (i.e memberRoleId repeats) in the Memberships table, I want to create an array of all the values as the struct without having to specify the list since its a long, wide table!

Im trying to collect up all rows by the common id into an array, but I want to easily include all the fields in the sturct without explicitly defining - is this possible?

From this...

```
      MemberRoleId,
      ARRAY_AGG (
        STRUCT( 
           MemberRoleId, MembershipId, MemberPartyId, MemberRoleId......     
        )
      )
    FROM
      Memberships
    GROUP BY
      MemberRoleId
```

to something like below with the * just saying I want the all the rows columns that matches that MemberRoleId thats grouped to be in the struct

```
      MemberRoleId,
      ARRAY_AGG (
        STRUCT( 
           * 
        )
      )
    FROM
      Memberships
    GROUP BY
      MemberRoleId
```

MemberRoleId,[{MemberRoleId,x,x,x,x,x,x,x},{MemberRoleId,y,y,y,y,y,y,y}]

but not have to explicitly define the struct schema for the array agg....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use below to achieve your goal

```
SELECT
  MemberRoleId,
  ARRAY_AGG (t)
FROM
  Memberships t
GROUP BY
  MemberRoleId
```

Comment: Ha likely the fastest answer ever missed the obvious sorry!